# Can't save $_POST array to database with function

Tags: php, arrays, function, post, for-loop

I have a form that has multiple inputs of the same name, resulting in an array. I want to pass this `$_POST` array to a function which will process and save the array into a database.

I've done this before with no problems without using a function, but now that I want to contain it all in a nice neat function call it won't do it and I'm not sure why?

The input/post variable in question is named `option[]` and is passed to the function as `$_POST['option']`. Here is the function:

```
function newVariant($name, $option) {
global $db;
global $table_prefix;
$table = $table_prefix . "variants";

$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $table(name) VALUES(:name)");
$query->bindParam(":name", $name);

if (!$query->execute()) {
    die(showMessage("Error!","There has been a problem saving your variant. Please try again or contact technical support if the problem persists.",""));
    }

$variant_id = $db->lastInsertId('id');

for($i = 0; $i < count($option); $i++) {
   if($option[$i] != "") {

      $table2 = $table_prefix . "variant_items";
      $query2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $table2(variant, option) VALUES(:variant, :option)");
      $query2->bindParam(":variant", $variant_id);
      $query2->bindParam(":option", $option[$i]);

      if (!$query2->execute()) {
         die(showMessage("Error!","There has been a problem saving your variant. Please try again or contact technical support if the problem persists.",""));
      }
   }
}

$redirect = renderLink("/beyond/?act=admin&sub=variants", "true");
showMessage("Saving variant...<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Refresh\" Content=\"1; URL=$redirect\">","","");
}
```

This is the error I'm getting in my log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option) VALUES(?, ?)' at line 1' in /Users/adampcollings/Sites/Hot Mint Development/beyond/php/functions/product.php:131
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/adampcollings/Sites/Hot Mint Development/beyond/php/functions/product.php(131): PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO bb_...')
#1 /Users/adampcollings/Sites/Hot Mint Development/beyond/html/admin/new-variant.php(5): newVariant('Test', Array)
#2 /Users/adampcollings/Sites/Hot Mint Development/beyond/php/html.php(19): include('/Users/adampcol...')
#3 /Users/adampcollings/Sites/Hot Mint Development/beyond/html/admin.php(10): subElement('admin', 'new-variant')
#4 /Users/adampcollings/Sites/Hot Mint Development/beyond/php/html.php(8): include('/Users/adampcol...')
#5 /Users/adampcollings/Sites/Hot Mint Development/beyond/index.php(14): siteElement('a in /Users/adampcollings/Sites/Hot Mint Development/beyond/php/functions/product.php on line 131
```

Comment: Please expand on "it won't do it." What do you expect to happen, and what really happens?

Comment: I'm expecting it to save the name to one table, and all the options to a different table in their own row while storing the ID of the parent with it. At the moment it is storing the parent name in the first query, but none of the options from the second.

Comment: Are any of your error conditions triggered? Do you get a message?

Comment: None of the errors are triggered, but it doesn't complete the function as there is no redirect at the end. It just shows whitespace where there should be something.

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting in your PHP configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment thread above, there are several things you should try.

First, always enable error reporting when debugging an application. To do this in your script, add:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to the top of your script.

Second, ensure that `$options` contains the data you expect. Somewhere in your code, add the following line:

```
var_dump($options);
```

This will show you the contents of `$options`. If it does not contain the values you expect, check your submission process.

Finally, if `$options` contains the expected data, check your table structure to ensure that your query matches and inserts the correct values.

EDIT: After you posted the MySQL error, I cross-checked the [MySQL Reserved Words list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html). The word 'option' is on the list. As such, the query is failing because the word is not recognized as a column name. Try surrounding the column name with backticks:

```
$query2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $table2(`variant`, `option`)...
```

Comment: Okay, I will try that. I have also added the PHP error into the original post.

Comment: Right, a var_dump on $options returns null. So it seems the array isn't getting passed to the function.

Comment: @Adam, see the edit to my answer. I think your column name `option` is conflicting with a MySQL reserved word.

Comment: Ah that was exactly it. Backticks solved it, thank you very much!